# Test of datastax java driver on cassandra and using nodetool

Tags: cassandra, datastax, nodetool

I was doing some test on datastax java driver with Eclipse on Mac Pro. Basically, in the eclipse, I was using prepared and batch statement to write (id, name), where id ranges from 10000 to 1000000 and names are student1 - student10000(according to the range of id).
    After every time I run the code in eclipse, everything goes well, then I use nodetool cfhistograms and proxyhistograms, and cfstats to check the results. However, it seems to be weird. As I was looking forward to see the read latency and write lantency to increase, as I add the range from 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000, the final result turns out to be decreasing on the latency.

For example, for the cfhistograms of 10,000 first table and 100,000 second table:
**Percentile  SSTables Write Latency**
50%         0               14
75%         0                20
95%         0                42
98%         0                60
99%         0                60
Min          0                 5
Max          0                179

and 100,000 below
**Percentile  SSTables Write Latency**
50%         0               10
75%         0                12
95%         0                24
98%         0                29
99%         0                42
Min          0                 3
Max          0                1109

Also, for the proxyhistogram, 10, 000:
**Percentile  Read Latency Write Latency**
50%         1331               72
75%         1916                103
95%         5722               215
98%         5722                310
99%         5722               372
Min          259                  30
Max          5722                11864

and 100,000 below:
**Percentile  Read Latency Write Latency**
50%         1331               42
75%         1916                50
95%         6866               103
98%         6866                149
99%         6866               215
Min          311                  18
Max          6866                61214

Anyone has any idea about this?

Thanks in advance!

Steven

Comment: What is your Topology, Replication Factor & Consistency Level for Write? Are you seeing any activity on Hints table?

Comment: @PuspenduBanerjee Actually, I've tested this driver on both amazon aws ec2 and local machine, which use replication factor to be networktopologystrategy(DC1:1, DC2:1) and simplestrategy(rf:1). For the consistency level I did not change anything, so I think it should be 1. For the hints table, where to check it and is there any effect of this? Thanks!

Comment: select * from system.hints; This will give hints stored for any node

Comment: @AravindChamakura  Thanks for the reply. I got 0 row from the hints:cqlsh:system> select * from hints;

 target_id | hint_id | message_version | mutation
-----------+---------+-----------------+----------

(0 rows)